# wordpress theme add left sidebar

Tags: html, css, wordpress, sidebar

http://judopassion.com/wordpress/

I would move the leftSidebar, that now is under sidebar on the right, to the left of the content like in this image:
[image]

What css code I have to add?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get it looking like the image on the right you'd have to re-order the markup on your template so that `<aside id="leftSidebar"></aside>` came before `<div id="content">` in the flow of the document.

[image: change markup in temmplate]

You'll also have to reduce the width of #content to 476px given all the existing padding etc.